# Programatically capture iPhone project's client-server communication?

Tags: ios, objective-c, client-server

I am looking for a simple programatic approach to be able to capture the client-server communication on an iPhone project.

My investigation so far introduced me to tools such as Charles (explained [How to monitor network calls made from iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128362/how-to-monitor-network-calls-made-from-ios-simulator))

Now I need to programatically monitor the client-server communication of an iOS project. I want it to be stand alone and separate from (NSlogging) the source code of the project where it sends requests.

For example by using Objective-C Categories and Extensions on maybe AFHTTPClient or other classes to capture not only http requests but all the requests.

Is this a good idea? any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what purpose do you want to capture this? What kind of data do you need? You already get a bunch of data by using NSUrlSession, you can capture httpresponses from that.

Comment: If possible I want to capture the REQUEST (method/parameters), the RESPONSE: (200, data), the URL for any communication between the iOS app and the server during run time. This is part of a dynamic analysis process. I want this to be as general as possible and not specific to a particular type of communication. I think I have to use Objective-C Categories and Extensions on a class that is common for any client-server session.

Comment: So before your call your networking code, log what you are sending, when you get a response back log that. I am assuming you have the code that talks to your server in a common shared function. For instance I have a class ApiConnection that is a wrapper for connecting to my server. I pass in the url to it, http type (post, get) and get back data.

Comment: Thanks! Right, there are different networking approaches and (third-party) libraries: AFNetworking, MKNetworkKit, NSURLConnection, FSNetworking, libcurl. So I ended up injecting the log code before and after the call where an app uses any of the approaches.