# Debugging network requests with iOS Simulator, network request data is not showing

Tags: xcode, macos, safari, simulator

I am trying to debug the network requests for a hybrid/webview cordova based application in the ios simulator, actually see the network requests in the Safari Web Inspector.  I am trying to use the Web Inspector within Safari to monitor the network requests to the server but all I see is the "timeline" graph, I don't see the actual URI requests.  Is there a way to enable this?

I build my application through xcode.  Launch the iOS simulator with iPad2 selected/iOS 8.1.  I then launch Safari and select the "ios simulator/index.html" to launch the web inspector.   And then click on network requests.  The resources tab pane is empty when I make web request calls.  Is there a way to fix this so I can see the url requests?

- Xcode: 6.1.1
- Safari: 7.1.3
- OSX: 10.9.5

Comment: I am getting this exact same thing. It would be great if someone knows the answer to this.

Comment: @AlainJacometForte Look at the answer below

Comment: If you're looking for an debugger, you might want to explore DebugSwift at github.com/DebugSwift/DebugSwift. It can be a helpful resource for your debugging needs!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if it's even possible to do that via web inspector or not but put option 1 just in case. I highly recommend you to go with Option 2 tho.

**Option 1**

First make sure you don't have anything filtered, then make sure recording is on as shown in picture.

[image: Steps to verify inspector is working]

**Option 2. RECOMMNDED**

Use an http monitoring tool. They are design to do that specific task plus you get many more options such as breakpoints, etc.

- [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com). (MAC) The best IMHO. You can set breakpoints and alter request/response if needed. And many other features.
- [HttpScoop](http://www.tuffcode.com/) (MAC) Easier to use, but less functionality.
- [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) (WINDOWS) Just in case.

PS. Some one might say [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), I know but it's too complicated for such work.

**[UPDATE 1]**
To make it clear you don't need to set any proxy on iOS simulator to get these tools working. In case of SSL connections you want to use charles and follow their [SSL guideline](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/using-charles/ssl-certificates/).

Comment: I ended up with Wireshark because it can be difficult to then configure the proxy (e.g. charles) within a simulator.  For example, if you need to deploy on a different device you have to reconfigure all of those settings.  But like your image shows, the recording is on, filters are empty, the network requests show little blue and green lines but I can't see the resources going through.

Comment: @BerlinBrown you don't have to setup any proxy for httpScoop neither for Charles. That's only if you want to use SSL. The only thing you need is to make sure you are listening on correct network interface.

Comment: I prefer option 2 with Charles

Comment: FYI using option 1 is not available on iOS Simulator

Answer (score 9):

I use [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io/) to monitor network traffic from the iOS simulator for the following reasons -

- It has a clear set of instructions on how to set it up with both [iOS
  simulators](https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/ios-simulator) and [Android emulators](https://docs.proxyman.io/debug-devices/android-device).
- It has a simple, intuitive UI, which makes it easy to work with.

[image]

Also, you might find it worthwhile going through [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128362/how-to-monitor-network-calls-made-from-ios-simulator).

Comment: This is such a great tool. Saved me countless hours. Thanks!