# How to monitor and debug network requests with Xcode on simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm coming from web dev and have gotten used using Chrome to inspect & debug network requests. Now I just started learning a bit of iOS dev :). So far I haven't found a simple way how to monitor and debug network requests when developing an iOS App and running it on simulator. Surely there must be a similar way of monitoring network activity of your App just like in Chrome - seeing request payload & headers and same with the response - body, headers, status code etc.

I did quick googling and it came up with third party solutions like `Charles` for example. But it seemed too complicated at first glance - install certificate on device/simulator etc. So to me it seems super strange that one would need go through such pain of installing and setting up third party tools just to see your APPs requests. Seems way too cumbersome and complicated for such common problem of APP development. Isn't there something that works out of the box inside Xcode? Some simple network monitoring utility?

P.S I found this - `Network instrument` inside Xcode https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/analyzing_http_traffic_with_instruments

But Network Instrument says :D

> Recording of 'Network Connections' is not supported in the Simulator.

Related question here, but is is old and again filled with cumbersome and complicated 3rd party tools:

[How to monitor network calls made from iOS Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11128362/how-to-monitor-network-calls-made-from-ios-simulator)

Thanks!

Comment: Try Proxeman for example